# C++ Builder Pattern Based on Configuration

Tags: c++, class, builder, builder-pattern

I found this [useful](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1121152#file-builder-cpp-L96) gist that introduced me into Builder Pattern Design.

**How would one implement this code to build a "Car" object with required and optional parameters based on configurations without writing dedicated builders?**

**Scenario 1**

Build a car with 3 wheels, no body and no engine.

**Scenario 2**

Build a car with 2 wheels, with a body and an engine.

**Scenario 3**

Build a car with 1 wheel, no body and no engine.

**Scenrion N**
Some other random combination.

And let's imagine the "Car" object requires at least one wheel to be built.

I have stumbled upon a blog post that mentions a state machine approach but it still seems a bit messy to me.

The post: https://blog.jayway.com/2012/02/07/builder-pattern-with-a-twist/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about following:
inject Configuration Context as an argument into method getCar() in class Director then build appropriate Car object there

comments in gist are self explanatory:
/* Builder is responsible for constructing the smaller parts */

/* Director is responsible for the whole process */

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was understanding that the director is managing the constructors. It is because of my lack of experience in C++ that I could not make the connection.

Comment: check this descriptionn of the Builder[link](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Builder/) maybe will help

Comment: Thanks. I see it is Java but I will try to read it and try to understand better the concept.